# InheritedWidget giving data as null down the widget tree Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to pass data from one widget to another widget down the tree. Here is my code which navigate from one screen to another:

```
final page = LanguagePreferenceProvider(child: UserNameScreen(),language: _currentNationality,);
            navigate(context, page);
```

`navigate()` method:

```
void navigate(BuildContext context, Widget page) {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2) => page,
        transitionsBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2, child) {
          return SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
                end: Offset(0, 0), begin: Offset(1, 0))
                .animate(anim1),
            child: page,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now in another screen I am using this to get the value:

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _selectedLanguage = LanguagePreferenceProvider.of(context).language;
```

My InheritedWidget class:

```
class LanguagePreferenceProvider extends InheritedWidget{
  final String language;

  LanguagePreferenceProvider({
    Widget child,
    this.language,
}) : super(child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(LanguagePreferenceProvider oldWidget) => language != oldWidget.language;

  static LanguagePreferenceProvider of(BuildContext context) => context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(LanguagePreferenceProvider);
}
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
The getter 'language' was called on null.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reality, it's not `language` that is `null` but the `LanguagePreferenceProvider`. Based on your example, I can theorize a likely scenario why it happens.

You have a widget tree that might look like this:

```
- MaterialApp
  + Navigator
    + LanguagePreferenceProvider
      + SomeUiWidgets
```

*Note:* there is a Navigator in MaterialApp by default.

Whenever you push a route to the Navigator, which you do, it's children are going away. Either completely replaced or pushed down on the stack of routes. In either case, lookuping up `LanguagePreferenceProvider.of(context)` might result in a `null` value, IF the new route's widget tree doesn't contain one.

To fix this, you could "life the state up", moving your inherited widget above the Navigator. This way, replacing routes won't destroy it. It's a way to persist state across routes with InheritedWidget.